# Changing genetic code of E. coli to accept synthetic amino acids?

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, molecular-genetics

I read in my Biology textbook that an experiment has been done in which one of   E. coli's stop codon has been altered to accept a synthetic amino acid. I do not get how it can be done. Taking the fact into account that every permutation of the 4 natural nitrogenous bases codes for a particular amino acid means that if the stop codon, let's say UGA, is altered to UUA it will code for Leucine. How does this leave a possibility for the production of a codon which codes for a synthetic amino acid? I will appreciate your kind explanation. Thank you a lot.

Comment: They would use the codon UGA to code for a synthetic amino acid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done by engineering a synthetic tRNA that can recognize the stop codon. The synthetic tRNA possesses a non-natural amino acid that is processed normally by the Ribosome and incorporated into the growing polypeptide chain.

Comment: This answer was accepted; however, it is still advisable that you add references :)